# Dalekjs Changing the Firefox port from 9006

Tags: javascript, firefox, dalekjs

This might sound like a stupid question, but where exactly do I set the port for firefox?  I tried adding the code to the config.js file in dalekjs\lib\dalek\config.js but it doesn't seem to do anything. Firefox still tries to use 9006 and fails.

Per the documentation:

> The Webdriver Server tries to open Port 9006 by default, if this port
>   is blocked, it tries to use a port between 9007 & 9096 You can
>   specifiy a different port from within your Dalekfile like so:
>
> "browsers": [{    "firefox": {
>        "port": 5555     }  }]

Where's the Dalekfile?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

in node_modules folder of project there are series of files called Dalekfile, search for them and add the browser to Dalekfile.json